# Selenium get the text from elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping website to get the factories data but I get the first factory data in each step in the loop
the page has 12 factories when I click in one of them that opens pop up I need to scrape these data

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


#### CONSTANT #####

URL='https://modon.gov.sa/ar/Partners/Factories/Pages/default.aspx'
chrome_driver_path = 'E:\programs\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'
AREA= 'الدمام الأولى'
### TO KEEP THE BROWSER OPEN WHEN SCRIPT IS CRASH #####
chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_option.add_experimental_option('detach', True)

##### CREATE THE DRIVER #########

## LOGIN##
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_option)
driver.get(url=URL)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

###### SWLWCTING THE AREA ######
select_area = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='select2-ctl00_ctl57_g_0b9a1f17_4953_4478_addd_249c1a935db0_ctl00_ddlICity-container')
select_area.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
dropdown_areas= driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.select2-results ul li')
for area in dropdown_areas:
    if area.text == AREA:
        area.click()
        break
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.form-group .btn').click()

factories= driver.find_elements(by= By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.row div .facListItem')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print(len(factories))
for factory in factories:
    factory_details= dict()
    factory.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    name= driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.modal-content .modal-header h4')
    print(name.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

I expect I get each name of the factories every time I open factory

Answer (score 0):

I have changed and refactored one part of your code as below:

```
for area in dropdown_areas:
    if area.text == AREA:
        area.click()
        break
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.form-group .btn').click()
time.sleep(5)
factories= driver.find_elements(by= By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.row div .facListItem')
print(len(factories))
for factory in factories:
    print (factory.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Result:**

```
12
الشركة السعودية لطلاء انابيب الاسلاك الكهربائيه والمقاولات
الشركة السعودية للخرسانة الجاهزة
الشركة السعودية للصناعات الاساسية
الشركة السعودية للصناعات الدوائية
الشركة السعوديه لطلاء الطرق المحدودة
الشركة الشرقيه لصناعة الكرتون ايسترن باك
الشركة الصناعية المتخصصه للزجاج
الشركة العربية السعودية لصناعة مواد التعبئة سابن
الشركة العربية السعودية لصناعة مواد التعبئة سابن
الشركة العربية السعودية لصناعة مواد التعبئة سابن شركة شخص واحد
الشركة العربية لتلبيس الاطارات
الشركة العربية للمعادن والكيماويات المحدودة

Process finished with exit code 0
```